# ciphertext A = plaintext(Base64 coding scheme)+2

Tags: java, android, base64

I have to apply Base64 Encoding but there is a "+2".. 
I have been trying to find about "+2" meaning but failed..

I think "ciphertext A = plaintext(Base64 coding scheme)" is usual Base64 Encoding..that is easy with JAVA like that..

```
json.put("REGVER",      Base64.encodeToString(strRegVer.getBytes(), 0));
```

but I want to know what differentiation betweewn above and "ciphertext A = plaintext(Base64 coding scheme)+2" is..

```
json.put("REGVER",      Base64.encodeToString(strRegVer.getBytes(), 0)+2);
```

Is this OK..? just +2 after Base64 encoding..?

Help me~~!! Thank you so much...

cyper.. bad guy from Matrix.. ^^;

Comment: What is the package of Base64 class?

Comment: I think "android.util.Base64" can be a answer of your question..
then.. Can you answer my Request...?

Comment: It just appends "2" to the value that is returned by the Base64.encodeToString(strRegVer.getBytes(), 0), it might be of significance to the JSON string before decoding.